# How to process data while the requested client is waiting for keyboard input using sockets in Python

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, encryption, aes, client-server

I am creating a chat using cryptography and I'm sending some requests to generate and share the key (AES) through sockets in python.
Half of the way it is working, but it gets stuck when I need to request something from the client because it is waiting for keyboard input.
A piece of Server code:

```
elif message["type_msg"] == b'A':
                add,rem =  message['data'].split(b'|')
                tipo = b'K'
                message = message["data"]

                for client_socket in clients:
                    # Send it to client
                    if get_clientPort(client_socket) == add.decode('utf-8'):
                        client_socket.send(tipo  + message_header(message) + message) <---------GETTING STUCK HERE
                        aes_key = receive_message(client_socket)
                        while aes_key == False:
                            aes_key = receive_message(client_socket)

                if aes_key['type_msg'] == b'k':
                    tipo = b'a'
                    message = aes_key['data']
                    for client_socket in clients:
                        # Send it to client
                        if get_clientPort(client_socket) == rem.decode('utf-8'):
                            client_socket.send(tipo  + message_header(message) + message)
```

Part of the client code:

```
elif tipo == b'a':
        if os.path.isfile(f"AES_key/{my_username}/{my_username}_{add}.pem"):
            aes_key=rsa_read_public(f"AES_key/{my_username}/{my_username}_{add}.pem")
        #request key
        else:
            tipo = b'A'
            req = f'{add}|{my_username}'
            req = req.encode('utf-8')
            message_header = f"{len(req):<{HEADER_LENGTH}}".encode('utf-8')
            client_socket.send(tipo +message_header + req) <---------GETTING STUCK HERE
            recKey = receive_message(client_socket)
            while recKey == False:
                recKey = receive_message(client_socket)

            aes_key = recKey['data']
            if not os.path.exists(f"AES_key/{my_username}/"):
                folder = os.makedirs(f"AES_key/{my_username}/")
            #save key
            key = io.open(f"AES_key/{my_username}/{my_username}_{add}.pem", 'wb')
            key.write(aes_key)
            key.close()
            aes_key = rsa_read_public(f"AES_key/{my_username}/{my_username}_{add}.pem")
            tipo = b'a'
```

It happens because the client is waiting for input by keyboard. I did the same process with RSA and worked because I did not need to call the client because I had the public key in the server.

I am using flags to determine the kind of encryption I want to and indicate which step is proceeding.

If you know an easier way, I am open to change the process.